# How to replace robots.txt with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, search-engine, robots.txt

I have a small situation where i have to remove my robots.txt file because i don't want and robots crawlers to get the links.

Also i want them to be accessible by the user and i don't want them to be cached by the search engines.

Also i cannot add any user authentications for various reasons.

So i am thinking about using mod-rewrite to disable search engine crawlers from crawling it while allowing all others to do it.

The logic i am trying to implement is write a condition to check if the incomming user agent is a search engine and if yes then re-direct them to 401.

The only problem is i don't know how to implement it. :(

Can somebody help me with it.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

I may be understanding you wrong, but I think

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

in robots.txt will do just what you want - not let any crawler in, while keeping website open for normal users.

Or do you need to specifically remove robots.txt (for what reason?) from the web server?

Comment: It will not prevent absolutely ALL crawlers to stop browsing your site (only those that do respect robots.txt -- all big search engines do that).. but it is definitely a way to start with.

Comment: Well there's no way to stop custom crawlers that don't respect robots.txt, because they can send whatever info necessary, including "proper" User-Agent.

Comment: I'm absolutely agree with you. This comment was rather addressed to OP than to you -- I just thought it's more appropriate to leave the comment here than under the question.

Comment: My main aim is to block any crawlers from getting the url of sensitive pages from the robots.txt, i am not bothered if they manually browse it or copy from it using the direct url. All i want it to prevent them from knowing those links exists from robots.txt and at the same time if any search engines like google or bing comes across that link, i don't want them to cache it or follow it. thats all.