# Why big websites like cnn are using robots.txt and not better htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

In my opinion is is not wise.

e.g. check this:

```
http://edition.cnn.com/robots.txt
http://www.bbc.co.uk/robots.txt
http://www.guardian.co.uk/robots.txt
```

according from this:

```
http://www.joomla.org/robots.txt
```

Joomla.org have not changed the default administration folder :D

E.g. prestashp page has a blank robots.txt file which is not perfect, but at least better in my opinion:

```
http://www.prestashop.com/robots.txt
```

Are these people stupid or they think that it is ok to know how they web strtucture look like?

Why are they not using htaccess to deny access for robots etc?

Comment: Isn't robots.txt the universally accepted way to tell robots to not access the site? What would you do with htaccess instead?

Comment: I can tell them with htaccess. With robots.txt you just let them know what they should pay attention to ;).

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505496/how-to-replace-robots-txt-with-htaccess

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `.htaccess` can't intuitively tell that a visitor is a search engine bot.

Most bots will identify themselves in the user-agent string, but some won't.

Robots.txt is accessed by all the bots looking to index the site, and unscrupulous bots are not going to

1. Identify themselves as a bot
2. Pay any attention to robots.txt (or they will deliberately disobey it).

Comment: The problem is that .htaccess can't intuitively tell that a visitor is a search engine bot.  - Sorry but you are not right. There are many ways how to do that using htaccess.

Comment: What if I set the user agent to that of Mozilla Firefox? You then can't tell.